# Проблема отправки данных формы методом fetch на react

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

У менять есть таблица и форма. Я вывожу данные с сервера и хочу добавить новые данные с запросом на сервер. Однако у меня проблема с правильной записью в json введенных данных. Программа почему-то читает только последнее поле для ввода и отправляет только последнее введенное значение. В моем коде закомментированная часть "[data]: ..." отправляет на сервер пустые значения(не undefinded). Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Ниже привожу пример данных json, Form.js, Table.js, App.js

```
[
{
_id: "600d76c4ae66af078a510ce1",
data: {
name: "Misha",
email: "tett",
age: "22"
},
__v: 0
}
]
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    initialState = {
        __v: '',
        _id: '',
        data: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            age: '',
        },
    }
    state = this.initialState;

    handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        this.setState({
            data: {
                [name] : value,
            }
            // [data]: {
            //     [name] : value,
            // }
        });
    }

    submitForm = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
        this.setState(this.initialState);

        const data = {
            data: {
                name: this.state.data.name,
                email: this.state.data.email,
                age: this.state.data.age,
            }
        };

        await fetch('http://178.128.196.163:3000/api/records', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
            .then(() => {console.log(data)});
    }

    render() {
        const {name, email, age} = this.state;

        return(
            <form>
                <label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='name'
                    id='name'
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='email'
                    id='email'
                    value={email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <label htmlFor='age'>Age</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='age'
                    id='age'
                    value={age}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type='button' value='Submit' onClick={this.submitForm} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default Form;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const TableHeader = () => {
    return (
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    )
}

const TableBody = (props) => {
    const rows = props.characterData.map((row, _id) => {
            return (
                <tr key={row._id}>
                    <td>{row._id}</td>
                    <td>{row._id}</td>
                    <td>{row._id}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(row._id)}>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
        return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>

}

const Table = (props) => {
    const {characterData, removeCharacter} = props;

    return (
        <table>
            <TableHeader />
            <TableBody characterData={characterData} removeCharacter={removeCharacter} />
        </table>
    )
}
export default Table;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';
import Form from './Form'

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        characters: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPeople()
    }

    getPeople() {
        fetch("http://178.128.196.163:3000/api/records")
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((result) => this.setState({characters: result,}))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    handleSubmit = (character) => {
        this.setState({characters: [...this.state.characters, character]})
    }

    removeCharacter = async (_id) => {
        const {characters} = this.state;

        await fetch('http://178.128.196.163:3000/api/records/' + _id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        })
            .then((result) => {
                return result.json();
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))

        this.setState({
            characters: characters.filter((character, i) => {
                return i != _id;
            })
        })



    }

    render() {
        const {characters} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
                <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> this.setState({
>    data: {
>      [name] : value,
>    }
> });
> ```

```
this.setState(state => ({
   data: {
     ...state.data,
     [name]: value,
   }
}));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена!